# ModSecurity and GeoIP geoLookup rule not doing anything

Tags: geoip, mod-security, mod-security2

I'm trying to get the following rule to work but it seems to be doing nothing:

```
# Test IP address and block by country code
SecGeoLookupDb /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "chain,id:20,drop,msg:'Block China IP address'"
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "@streq CN HK"
```

​I have had the GeoIP database installed for a while and used it successfully for other purposes, so this isn't the problem.

As it stands the above rule does nothing - no error, and no blocking.
Given the huge amount of China based traffic I've been receiving the logs should be absolutely full...

The version of Modsecurity I'm running is 2.9.2-ubuntu18.04.19091318 and the server is running Plesk.
I'm wondering if there is anything else that I need to set up to get this working, or if there is at least any way of testing the various layers...

Edit: I set up Modsecurity debugging and there are lots of entries showing:

```
No geo data for "IP_ADDRESS_HERE" (country 0).
```

Not sure why it wouldn't be finding any of these as the GeoIP.dat file is there and I can successfully run geoiplookup from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following:

```
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "@streq CN HK"
```

Meaning the country code has to exactly match `CN HK` when in reality it will be `CN` or `HK`.

I think you want the following to match any one of the listed countries.

```
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "@pm CN HK"
```

Comment: Afraid this doesn't help. I had tried this along with using just the single country code with both @ pm and @ streq.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output when you configure libModSecurity for compilation?

You should have some output such as

> ModSecurity - v3.x.x for Linux
>
> Optional dependencies    + GeoIP/MaxMind     ....found